# Errors usually but within EXISTS sub-query it runs

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Is the following problematic?

```
DELETE a
FROM WHAnalysis.dbo.tb_r12027dxi_CalculatedData a
WHERE EXISTS
        (
        SELECT * 
        FROM WHAnalysis.dbo.tb_r12027dxi_CalculatedData b
        WHERE 
            b.[Past28Days] = 1 AND
            a.[Index] = b.[Index]
        HAVING SUM(b.Amount) = 0
        )
```

Reason I'm slightly uneasy about using the above script is that if I run the following it errors:

```
SELECT * 
FROM WHAnalysis.dbo.tb_r12027dxi_CalculatedData b
WHERE 
    b.[Past28Days] = 1
HAVING SUM(b.Amount) = 0
```

I understand why this script errors => the select is not grouped on anything therefore the processor does not like the aggregation in the HAVING clause.

But as a sub-query this error does not occur - why? Is this a  problematic approach?

**EDIT**

Ended up using the following:

```
DELETE a
FROM WHAnalysis.dbo.tb_r12027dxi_CalculatedData a
WHERE a.[Index] IN
    (
    SELECT [Index] 
    FROM WHAnalysis.dbo.tb_r12027dxi_CalculatedData
    WHERE [Past28Days] = 1
    GROUP BY [Index] 
    HAVING SUM(Amount) = 0
    )
```

But as suggested in answer the following is more readable by simply adding the GROUP BY into the sub-query:

```
DELETE a
FROM WHAnalysis.dbo.tb_r12027dxi_CalculatedData a
WHERE EXISTS
    (
    SELECT * 
    FROM WHAnalysis.dbo.tb_r12027dxi_CalculatedData b
    WHERE 
            b.[Past28Days] = 1 AND
            a.[Index] = b.[Index]
    GROUP BY b.[Index]
    HAVING SUM(b.Amount) = 0
    )
```

Comment: From my testing, it seems that any error in a exists clause is ignored - eg: `SELECT * FROM table where EXISTS (Select 2/0)` . But I can't explain why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is legal to omit group by and still perform aggregations, therefore `having` is still a way of limiting results:

```
select sum(x)
from
(
  select 1 x union all select 2
) a
having sum(x) = 3
```

`Exists()` work because everything in select list is ignored. `Exists()` looks for rows only, and terminates as soon as one is found. You might add `group by b.Index` to make intent clear to anyone reviewing the code later, or rewrite it using inner join and derived table.

```
DELETE a
FROM WHAnalysis.dbo.tb_r12027dxi_CalculatedData a
INNER JOIN
        (
        SELECT b.[Index]
        FROM WHAnalysis.dbo.tb_r12027dxi_CalculatedData b
        WHERE 
            b.[Past28Days] = 1
        GROUP BY b.[Index]
        HAVING SUM(b.Amount) = 0
        ) b1
   ON a.[Index] = b1.[Index]
```